# Google Play API returning error 401

Tags: android, google-play, android-gradle-plugin

I'm using [gradle-play-publisher](https://github.com/Triple-T/gradle-play-publisher) library to upload my app to Google Play, but I get error 401 Unauthorized when executing the publishing task.
My dev account at Google Play and service account at Dev Console are set up. Play API is enabled.

As I see from build logs, the first request sent is:

```
POST https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token
```

I get 200 OK and the following json:

```
{
  "access_token" : "< some value here>",
  "token_type" : "Bearer",
  "expires_in" : 3600
}
```

Then the next request is sent:

```
POST https://www.googleapis.com/androidpublisher/v2/applications/< my app's package name here>/edits
```

First of all, I noticed this header among others:

```
Authorization: <Not Logged>
```

And second, I get this error as a response

```
401 Unauthorized
WWW-Authenticate: Bearer realm="https://accounts.google.com/", error=invalid_token
```

Has anyone faced the same issue? Everything seems to be set up correctly, so I have no idea what went wrong. Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

Your error means that

**server responded with 401 (Unauthorized) status code but failed to provide a single auth challenge (WWW-Authenticate header)** *thus making it impossible for HttpClient to automatically recover from the authentication failure.*

> Check your HTTP POST request in you application which might expect
>   some short of credentials in the HTML form

I hope that you are already testing your rest API(url) by using POSTMAN google chrome extension.

**Now,if your rest api works fine then consider about using that in your code, step by step try to figure out the following**

> 1. server implementation is wrong or client side implementation wrong or url
> 2. parameters are wrong
> 3. check for `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />` in your
>      AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: Thanks for your response. The problem is: I do not send any of these requests manually. The library I mentioned in my question is supposed to do everything for me. And it does seem to work for others.

Comment: please check the following link: http://pcsupport.about.com/od/findbyerrormessage/a/401error.htm

Comment: Thank you, I'm totally aware of what error 401 means. As I've already mentioned: I do not have access to code that is sending these requests. It's inside the library. The only thing I can control is project configuration at Google API. So I was hoping to get an answer like 'yeah, I faced the same issue, just go [here] and turn on [this feature]'